# How can i remove NaN values between increments in my counter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've setup a counter for my react component. It gets a number(5) from database and then multiples it every second, it works fine but I see `NaN` values between increments like `5-NaN-10-NaN-15-NaN` and so on. How can I fix this?
Below is my code, thanks in advance.

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react'
import firebase from '../config/Fire'

function useTimes(){
    const [kullanici,setTimes] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('kullanici')
            .doc('gNfFy0uEsk5OvrZOfkGm')
            .onSnapshot((doc)=>{
                const newTimes = doc.data()

                setTimes(newTimes)
            })

    },[])

    return kullanici
}
function carp(value){
  let counter=1;
  setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = value*counter
    counter++;
  },1000);
}

const Main = () => {
    const kullanici =useTimes()
    return(
        <div>
        <li>Silver: <span id="count">{carp(kullanici.silver)}</span></li>
        </div>
    )
  }


export default Main
```

Comment: NaN is a shortcut for 'not a number' and it is appear when you try do math operation on a string

Comment: Show the value of `newTimes`?

Comment: Try to avoid using `document.getElementById()`.

Comment: @zynkn what can i use instead of it? when i use return value*counter in that line instead of document.getElementById() it returns nothing.

Comment: @JosephD. the value of kullanici.silver is 5 in database and when script starts it counts like 5-NaN-10-NaN-15-Nan and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid modifying the DOM directly (`carp()`), let React handle it. This causes unpredictable behaviour due to React's render cycle.

Move your interval into a hook, move your counter into state.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

function useInterval(callback, delay) {
  const savedCallback = useRef();

  // Remember the latest callback.
  useEffect(() => {
    savedCallback.current = callback;
  }, [callback]);

  // Set up the interval.
  useEffect(() => {
    function tick() {
      savedCallback.current();
    }
    if (delay !== null) {
      let id = setInterval(tick, delay);
      return () => clearInterval(id);
    }
  }, [delay]);
}

function useTimes(){
  const [kullanici,setTimes] = useState([])
  useEffect(()=>{
    // Just using setTimeout here to simulate a database call
    setTimeout(() => {
      setTimes({silver: 5});
    }, 1000)
  }, [setTimes])
  return kullanici
}

function App() {
  const kullanici = useTimes();
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1);
  useInterval(() => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  }, 1000)

  return (
    <div>
      <li>
        Silver: <span id="count">{
          kullanici.silver ? count * kullanici.silver : ''
        }</span>
      </li>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `Number()` in your code:

```
function carp(value){
  let counter=1;
  setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = Number(value)*counter
    counter++;
  },1000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of `kullanici.silver`? `number` or `string`? If it's  `string`, the result of `document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = value*counter` will be `NaN`.

Comment: it was string and i changed it to number it still happens, also it shows numbers as expected but in between i shows NaN like getting it from 2 different sources.